# unable to commit in git from another directory

Tags: git

[image: This is the error that I get when I try to commit after adding files to git.]

1. I initially created a git repo from my folder which was fine
2. the I updated a file in the same directory structure.
   My dir name is "gitdir" in c:,  I created another copy of the same under a folder named "something".
3. I'm trying to update my changes to the files in the repository from the updated files in the "something folder" without disturbing my backup folder gitdir so that I can test my git works fine without changing my gitdir.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Could you include it.

Comment: I tried more, I cloned my existing repo to my system then updated the files. after updating once I add the files to git, and then enter git commit it gives me the above screen. It is asking me to commit but there is no place where I can type and do commit again

Answer (score 0):

I could not properly understand the question, but looking at your terminal, I can see from your terminal that there is no commit message provided.

And, also, there is clear warning that lines starting with # will be ignored, and empty message aborts the commit.

Since all your lines are starting with #, the empty message is aborting the commit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write the commit message in the first line above the comments(lines starting with #). If you can't write: Press `i` to enter inline insert mode, then type the description at the very top.
2. Press `ESC` first to get out from editing. (in windows/vi)
3. Then write (In Emacs: `CTRL+X` `CTRL+S` to save then `CTRL+X` `CTRL+C` to quit) 
   (In Vi: `:wq` or `:wq!` and then `Enter` to close the commit editor).